# How to write my own max function

Tags: ruby, methods, max

I know that there is a max function from the Enumerable library in Ruby.

However, I'm trying to figure out how to write my own max method in which the largest number in an array is figured out.

How do I do that? I'm really at loss because when I Google it, all I keep getting is the max function itself.

Any help/advice would be helpful!

Comment: Would you like `array.sort.last` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another naive approach is -

```
list = [3,4,2,5,6,7,8,2,5,1,4,4,6]

def maximum(list) 
  len = list.size - 1
  maximum = list[0]

  for i in 1..len
    if maximum < list[i]
        maximum = list[i]
    end
  end
  maximum
end

puts maximum(list) 
# >> 8
```

Here is the graphical explanation(taken from this [link](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/05/21/computer-algorithms-minimum-and-maximum/)) -

[image]

Comment: thank you! This really helps since it doesn't rely on other functions, and I can break it apart further to try to understand it more.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 approaches: `Enumerable#each` (imperative) or `Enumerable#reduce` (usually functional, depends on how you use it). I prefer functional solutions, so I'd write:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_max
    reduce { |current_max, x| x > current_max ? x : current_max }
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you! I appreciate this as another way to look at this method. And also for raising the issue of imperative vs. functional way of doing things since that didn't even occur to me.